# Where are the spell addiction rules?

Tags: spells, shadowrun-sr5

In SR4 you had spell addiction rules: when you used the euphoria equivalent too often on the same target, or were too successful, the target could become addicted to the feeling of that spell. However I couldn't find anything like this in the rules for SR5.

Does this still exist in Shadowrun 5, or was it dropped? If it still exists, where do I find those rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### That rule is gone

The *Street Grimoire* (5ed source book for magic users) has a new version of the **Euphoria** spell, which includes the effects of Euphoria and Orgasm from 4ed, but there is no mention of the spell effect being addictive.

> This set of spells provides the spellcaster with an unusual set of non-lethal tools to distract his enemies by forcing great pleasure upon them. Euphoria envelops the target in the stimulating throes of a great high comparable to an **empathogenic drug high or sexual climax**.
>
> Many magicians utilize this spell in their private lives, granting willing targets a thrilling ecstasy. However, using this spell on unwilling subjects is considered a criminal act by law enforcement officers in many jurisdiction.
>
> Spellcasters known to excessively cast this set of spells may gain an unsavory reputation. Each net hit scored by the spellcaster applies a –1 dice pool modifier to all of the targets’ actions as they are distracted by the sensation.
>
> At the gamemaster’s discretion, a character who suffers a dice pool modifier higher than his Willpower is completely incapacitated and preoccupied. Euphoria affects a single target; Opium Den is an area spell.

Since it says it is similar to a sexual climax, there is no need for any addiction ruling anymore, since only those with *nymphomania* would feel addicted to sexual acts. Being already addicted to [empathogenic drugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empathogen%E2%80%93entactogen) also would have a similar result when being affected by this spell i believe.

The spell isn't as strong as the real stuff, but should probably count as your weekly dosage.

Comment: Adding as a comment: it was not only the euphoria equivalent spell that had the rule (it was a general one, but euphoria I think was one of the most used spells where it came up). So no mentioning of it in the street grimoire at all.

Comment: I belive only foci are addictive now, unless you have some negative quality that applies specifically to spells, but that seems to be house-rule territory now with 5ed.

Comment: If you still want to simulate it, the rules for Addiction in general starts on page 413 of the Core Book. Given the description, I'd rate it as being a psychological addiction on-par with the drug Bliss (rating 5, threshold 3). But that's just my take on it if you want to simulate the addiction to the spell.